# How to select/exclude specific conditions or cell types for further analysis with Limma?

Tags: r, bioconductor, limma

I'm new to R and Limma, and I tried to analyze a data set using the Limma guide. So far, so good, but now I want to include only 3 of the 5 cell types I have in my data set in "y" and any further analysis. How do I "select" or "exclude" conditions/cell types I defined in the targets file?

```
targets <- readTargets()
x <- read.ilmn(files="Einzelanalyse_nonorm_nobkgd.txt",ctrlfiles="ControlProbeProfile_nonorm_nobkgd.txt")
y <- neqc(x)
expressed <- rowSums(y$other$Detection < 0.05) >= 3
y <- y[expressed,]
plotMDS(y,labels=targets$condition)
```

Comment: welcome to SO. For others to help, can you provide an example dataset and also make the code above reproducible for others? Otherwise the code above doesn't make sense

Comment: Looking quickly, you can subset whatever y is , by doing what you did with ```expressed```, you get a boolean to decide which columns to include, and do y[,...]